# when key is unknown, how to get the value

Tags: javascript, object, key

Look this for example

```
var obj = {"name1":"jack"}; 
var key = "name1"; //get it by a function 
var value = obj.key;//get undefined 
value = obj.name1;//get "jack"
```

If I don't kwon the key, here is name1. But I can get "name1" by a function. how I can get the value "jack".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for an array with all enumerable keys of the object. Then iterate the array and access the property of the object by using bracket notation ([property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)).

```js
var object = { name1: "jack" },
    keys = Object.keys(object);

keys.forEach(key => console.log(object[key]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a function to loop through your object and log it's keys with their respective values you could do this:

```
var object = { name1: "Jack"};
function getValues(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var k in keys) {
        //This will print out the key as well as the value
        //Where keys[key] = key and obj[keys[key]] is the value
        console.log("Key: " + keys[k] + "\nValue: " + obj[keys[k]]);
    } 
}
getValues(object);
```